# Do i need mockito in spring boot project

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am working on a `REST Spring Boot` sample project, which does:

1. Client Application hits an end point with valid request
2. Using request will run the database query
3. Fetch the result and assign back to Model object and send as rest response.

In this process, I hardly write business conditional statements. Do I really need `Mockito` to the `Controller` ,`DAO` and `Service` layers ?

I can do the same thing by hitting the end point with request.

Comment: Do you really need to write tests? Well no. But this is regarded as bad practice. Conversely, you should write unit tests alongside your integration-/ end-to-end tests. Keep in mind that unit tests are in general less expensive (i.e. they execute faster) and thus shorten the agile development cycle.

Comment: If what you're doing is trivial, and what you're using are mostly Spring components (Controllers, Repositories, RestTemplate, etc), than they're already tested. Write a unit test only for your core logic classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a mockito. You can test your rest by hitting the rest by a valid request. But with writing tests, you can run many tests for the same rest for different scenarios with one click. SO you need to write tests to cover all the testing scenarios with one click. on the other hand, if you would test all scenarios through real requests, you need a lot of time and you may make invalid tests. Fianlly, you need a mockito so that you can proceed with unit tests.